# Possible to find all Windows processes preventing automatic sleep, w/o admin rights?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-10, power-management, sleep-mode

The command `powercfg -requests` will provide a list of processes that are currently preventing a Windows 10 device from automatically entering sleep mode.  However, the command requires administrator permissions.  Asking for admin access just to perform a simple informational query seems far from ideal.

So is it possible to query the Windows 10 API for a similar list, in a user-space application?

These processes are passing `SetThreadExecutionState()` the flags `ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED` or `ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED`.  But I don't see any function to query a list of registered execution states.

Comment: Submit a feature request to MS.

Comment: There is no API for this. But you can use `CreateProcess()` to spawn `powercfg` and then parse its output. That will not address the permissions issue, though. Some things can only be done by an admin, you have to live with it.

Comment: Do it in a Windows Service then access the service from a GUI application.