# Get Power Cfg / Requests Information in c#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, sleep

I am trying to retrieve the information from powercfg /requests in my application. ie.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg /requests
DISPLAY:
None.

SYSTEM:
[DRIVER] \FileSystem\srvnet
An active remote client has recently sent requests to this machine.

AWAYMODE:
None.

EXECUTION:
None.

PERFBOOST:
None.

I am essentially trying to get a list of what is preventing the computer from sleeping so that I can list it internally in my application.

Any help in pointing me to how to retrieve this information would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36826733/possible-to-find-all-windows-processes-preventing-automatic-sleep-w-o-admin-rig there is no API to do this right now.